# Is there an ExpressionEngine current gold price plugin/module?

Tags: module, plugin

Client is looking to have a current gold price on their website, looking to see if there is a EE plugin or would anyone recommend a third party plugin?

[image]

Something just like on this websites header: http://polyus.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

Guess you could display an rss feed with the current gold price. Something like this: http://www.24hgold.com/english/rss.aspx